# What <queries> tags should be added for these methods?

Tags: java, android

I have these 3 methods that require the `<queries>` tag in the manifest for Android 11. Problem is I can't find exactly what to add in the queries tag as I can't find these specific cases:

- Get a list of installed apps. Needs `<queries>` tag for `queryIntentActivities()`:

  ```
   final PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
   Intent main = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null);
   main.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
   packages = pm.queryIntentActivities(main, 0);
  ```
- Share the app. Needs `<queries>` tag for `resolveActivity()`:

  ```
       Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
       sharingIntent.setType("text/plain");
       sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, getString(R.string.per_app_rotation_for_android));
       String shareBody = "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.goodweathercorp.perapprotation";
       sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, shareBody);
       if (sharingIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
           startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, getString(R.string.share)));
       } else {
           Toast.makeText(this, R.string.no_share_apps_detected, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
       }
  ```
- Send Email. Needs `<queries>` tag for `resolveActivity()`:

  ```
       Intent emailSelectorIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO);
       emailSelectorIntent.setData(Uri.parse("mailto:"));
       Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
       emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{"goodweathercorp@gmail.com"});
       emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, getString(R.string.email_subject));
       emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, sendEditText.getText());
       emailIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
       emailIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
       emailIntent.setSelector(emailSelectorIntent);
       if (emailIntent.resolveActivity(getContext().getPackageManager()) != null) {
               startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, getString(R.string.choose_client)));
       } else {
               Toast.makeText(getContext(), R.string.no_apps_detected, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
       }
  ```

Note: For `resolveActivity()`, replacing it with a try/catch block doesn't work there's no exception thrown if no apps are detected on the device.

Comment: "replacing it with a try/catch block doesn't work there's no exception thrown if no apps are detected on the device" -- that is because you are using `Intent.createChooser()`.

Comment: What do I use instead?

Comment: You could just call `startActivity(sharingIntent)` and `startActivity(emailIntent)`. Those will throw the `ActivityNotFoundException` if there are no matches.

Comment: For your first one, see https://gitlab.com/commonsguy/cw-android-r/-/blob/master/QueryPackages/src/delta/AndroidManifest.xml#L5-11. For your second one, you should use `<action>` and `<type>` elements. For your third one... I have not experimented with `setSelector()` and so I do not know if you need `<queries>` entries for both `Intent` structures or just the outer one. Personally, I'm happy just letting the chooser show the "no apps" bottom sheet.

Comment: For the first one I tried adding the `<category>` tag but I get the error "Element category is not allowed here". What is causing this? For the second one should it be `<action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND"/> <data android:mimeType="text/plain"/>`? For the third one I need to tell the user what kind of app is required if he doesn't have it, like for example an email app.