# How can a NotificationListenerService use getApplicationInfo on Android 11 (API 30)?

Tags: android

Android 11 (API 30) adds [restrictions](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/11/privacy/package-visibility) about installed packaged visibility, which is excellent for user privacy. However, this means a NotificationListenerService is no longer able to load a notification's app name or icon with `context.packageManager.getApplicationInfo(packageName, 0)`. Are there any good workarounds for this?

The solutions that I've discovered are:

- `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES" />`
- `<queries><intent><action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" /></intent></queries>` [like so](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67043062/how-to-add-the-queries-tag-in-the-manifest)

However, these seem like excellent ways to be banned from the store. Are there any other solutions for a NotificationListenerService to get the application info objects related to active notifications?